# Borland c++ 5.02 file handling issue

Tags: html, c++

I am making a Borland C++ program for my school project that makes a text file and allows the user to make his own HTML page by selecting inputs from a menu. Is there a way I can rename the resulting text file so it has an extension of .html, so when I close the C++ program, it saves the file with an extension of .html directly?

Comment: Putting aside the issue of using a really really old compiler, can you post some of your code ? Is it a GUI app ? I would tend to think that you are using a Windows save file dialog with ".txt" extension as the default, or something related, but we can't be sure unless you give more details.

Comment: No it is not a GUI app. Forgive me for my poor information , i am a begginer at this :/

Comment: Then I presume it must be a simple issue in writing a file using a `std::fstream`, but then again, can't be sure unless you post some code.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  It sounds like you're saying you initially save the file as a .txt but later want to rename it as a .html.  Why not just initially save it as a .html?

Comment: @andand , yea and what i would like to know is how i could save it as .html without saving it as .txt

Comment: @pranavnairtech When you open the file for writing (however you do it), specify the name of the file you want.  It would be helpful to see some code describing exactly how you're opening the file.  Somebody could then help you craft some code which will open the file with the name you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably be easier to just open the file with the exact filename and extension you want rather than renaming the file afterwards. However there are cases where you would want to do this such as writing to a temporary file to preserve the existing file in case of an error. If this is the case there are options. Unfortunately there are no features in the *standard* libraries to accomplish this and you will need to rely on either system specific calls or use a library like Boost that abstracts this. Since you are appear to be on Windows you can use the [`MoveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx) or [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API calls.

```
if(!MoveFile("originalfilename.txt", "newfilename.html"))
{
    DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();

    // ... handle error code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/?kw=system) command executes an instruction on the command line.  So you could do something like:

```
system("ren output.txt output.html");
```

In your case you'll probably need to do some string concatenation to insert the correct file names into the string containing the DOS command you want the system to execute.